# How to store Ajax uploaded documents before model has been created and assigned a primary key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm really looking for a best approach for how to tackle this one.

I have a page for creating a new object, let's call it a "Report".

This is how it needs to perform:

There are the usual text boxes and text areas for creating a report.

I have functionality for ajax uploading documents.

When complete the user clicks "create" and the report is entered in the database.

**The Problem**

How can I upload documents via Ajax and store them logically in the file system when I don't yet have a primary key for report? Ideal file system structure would be /upload/docs/[userid]/[reportid]/.

Doing the uploads after the user has created a report isn't an option due to customer requirements.

Any approach you can suggest would be helpful :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have similar requirements, and a structure close to yours which is like :  `upload/[filetype]/[customer_id]/[file-UUID]`

We're creating a Unique ID (timestamp+userID+hash or something like that) then store that file and bind the UUID in the database when the user decide to create his document